# ember 2.0 data and models are changed

Tags: ember.js, model, ember-data

Previously, in Ember (v1.12x) I could do this:

```
App.Test = DS.Model.extend({
    "test-id": attr(),
    "test-message": attr()
});
```

In the Ember Inspector/Tools... it would show up in my model.  In Ember 2.2, if I do the same thing... it crashes the Ember Inspector with the following error:

> Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() to set the `content` property (of ) to ``.

Please understand I'm not using CLI here, simply running an example outside of Node. Is there something else that needs to be defined or a work around to get Ember Data working with Adapters and Model defiitions?